# Get the __file__ of the function one level up in the stack

Tags: python, stack, filepath

I've found that I'm using this pattern a lot :

```
os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), file_path)
```

so I've decided to put in a function in a file that has many such small utilities:

```
def filepath_in_cwd(file_path): 
    return os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), file_path)
```

The thing is, `__file__` returns the *current* file and therefore the current folder, and I've missed the whole point. I could do this ugly hack (or just keep writing the pattern as is):

```
def filepath_in_cwd(py_file_name, file_path): 
    return os.path.join(os.path.dirname(py_file_name), file_path)
```

and then the call to it will look like this:

```
filepath_in_cwd(__file__, "my_file.txt")
```

but I'd prefer it if I had a way of getting the `__file__` of the function that's one level up in the stack. Is there any way of doing this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should do it:

```
inspect.getfile(sys._getframe(1))
```

[`sys._getframe(1)`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys._getframe) gets the caller frame, [`inspect.getfile(...)`](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html#inspect.getfile) retrieves the filename.