# Python: __file__ of the caller

Tags: python

I want to define a utility function `f()` in my module `m` such that

1. if `m.f()` is invoked in `/foo/a.py`, it returns `/foo/a.py`
2. if `m.f()` invoked in `/bar/baz/b.py`, it returns `/bar/baz/b.py`

Intuitively I'd explain `f()` as "it returns `__file__` of the caller" but how can I really implement that (if possible at all?)

Note `def f(): return __file__` returns `/path/to/m.py` wherever I call `m.f()` and that's not what I want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the \_\_file\_\_ of the function one level up in the stack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11757801/get-the-file-of-the-function-one-level-up-in-the-stack)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

some.py:

```
m.f()
```

m.py:

```
import inspect
import os

def f():
    return os.path.relpath(
            inspect.stack()[1][1],
            basePath)
    # returns path to caller file relative to some basePath
```

Comment: Well, `inspect.stack()[1][1]` was just OK for my purpose

Comment: From version 3.5, a named tuple is returned, allowing for a more readable version: `inspect.stack()[1].filename`.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the `inspect` module. It has a [handy `stack()` method](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/inspect.html#inspect.stack) that returns the entire call stack, each element of which includes the filename. You just need to extract the last one.

Answer (score 2):

`__file__` is an attribute of the module loaded. So `m.__file__` will always give the path of the file from which `m` was loaded. To make it work for any module, you should call the attribute for that particular module.

```
import module

def f(m): return m.__file__

print f(module)
```