# How can I preserve the name of a middleman file whilst importing the logic from another module

Tags: python, module

Is there a way I can retrieve the name of a middleman module using imported functions?

In the same working directory:

top_level.py:

```
execfile('./middle_module.py')
# output of get_filename() is base_module.pyc
```

middle_module.py:

```
import base_module
base_module.get_filename() # how can I get this to be middle_module.py?
```

base_module.py:

```
def get_filename():
    print(__file__)
```

Edit: I'd like to avoid using CL arguments as this would need to be platform agnostic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing arguments to execfile in python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45185425/passing-arguments-to-execfile-in-python-2-7)

Comment: Why are you using execfile?

Comment: @user2357112 because I want to be explicit in the fact that `top_level` is merely chaining together multiple middle modules together. Importing the middle modules would imply there is some functionality to them which is untrue since the middle_modules are all currently running non-adaptable code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer here: [Get the __file__ of the function one level up in the stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11757801/get-the-file-of-the-function-one-level-up-in-the-stack)

top_level.py:

```
execfile('./middle_module.py')
# output of get_filename() is now middle_module
```

middle_module.py:

```
import base_module
base_module.get_filename() # refrences middle_module now
```

base_module.py:

```
import sys
import inspect
# get name of process one stack level above
def get_filename():
    print inspect.getfile(sys._getframe(1))
```